# Like operator over a collection

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I have a table `tag` and i want to retrieve records when `tag.tagname` contains any string of a array of string.

I try this query but it dosen't work :

```
 @Query("select tag from Tag tag "
         + " where tag.tagname like %:tags% ")
 Set<XX> findXXByTags(@Param("tags") String[] tags);
```

Answer (score 1):

and nor should it. The JPA spec says clearly enough that the thing after "LIKE" is a string value. Yours isn't

Comment: but there not a solution to this issue ?

Comment: field LIKE %val1% OR field LIKE %val2% etc

Comment: i have a array so i don't know the values or their numbers.

Comment: obviously you know the values ... they're in the array, so you construct the JPQL dynamically. Job done.

Comment: You also can not put the % in the query. The % must be on the value in the param (ex: .setParameter("tag", "%" + tag + "%")